# Spring Batch Application running twice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a springboot application that uses Spring Batch. But it seems like it's being loaded twice when I try to run it. Below is the output that I'm getting:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM2TD.png)

Here's the Main Application

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvwez.png)

Here's the Scheduler config:

[Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSSo1.png)

Here's the Batch config:

[Batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5riLn.png)

Here are the two tasklets:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
public class CreateXmlFileTask implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("originalFile")
    CsvToXmlService csvToXml;

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception
    {
        log.info("Start..");
        ...
        log.info("Done..");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}

@Log4j2
@Component
public class ReadDeCsvFileTask implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("originalFile")
    CsvToXmlService csvToXml;

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception
    {
        log.info("start..");
        ...
        log.info("done..");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Do you think it is being loaded twice because it is logged twice? If so this could be an issue in you log configuration.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, you are absolutely right!!! Genius! Thank you for saving my precious time!!!